# How to name nested elements using BEM and SMACCS

Tags: html, css, naming-conventions, bem, smacss

I just started out using BEM and SMACCS for my stylesheets but have run into some trouble as far as naming deeply nested elements in the DOM. Say for instance I have a div called `.main-container`. Nested inside the first level of the `main-container` is an additional div which by convention would be named `.main-container__article`.

```
<div class="main-container>
  <div class="main-container__article></div>
</div>
```

This is where things get confusing. Inside that article div let's say I have a header followed by a paragraph that has a nested span tags. Do I continue prepending classes with `main-container__article` as so?

```
<div class="main-container>
  <div class="main-container__article>
    <h1 class="main-container__article__header">Heading</h1>
    <p class="main-container__article__copy">
      <span class="main-container__article__copy__intro-text>Example text.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How far down does the rabbit hole go when it comes to naming parent/child elements? Is there a point where you reset at the second-level element and go from there?

```
<div class="main-container>
  <div class="article>
    <h1 class="article__header">Heading</h1>
    <p class="article__text">
      <span class="article__text__intro-text>This is example text.</span> for a paragraph 
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

BEM naming shouldn't resemble DOM structure because otherwise you won't be able to change markup without changes in CSS.

So for your example I'd make it like this:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h1 class="article__header">Heading</h1>
    <p class="article__copy">
      <span class="article__intro-text">Example text.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's also a quite powerful thing called **mixes**, which gives possibility to mix different BEM entities on the same DOM node:
    
      
        Heading
        
          Example text.

So now you may apply CSS to **article** block and **main-container__article** element separately which is very useful when you need to reuse **article** outside **main-container**.

Comment: So with this in place how would you target an `.article` div that belongs to `.main-container` without violating the conventions of SMACCS: `.main-container .article`?

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-container__article__copy__intro-text
```

definitely doesn't help the readability and maintainability of your stylesheets.

I suggest to break such giant blocks into several smaller blocks. If you do this, you can reuse your styles - in your example you couldn't use the article-block somewhere else.

I would "reset" everytime you can encapsulate a block which can potentially be used in several places in your app/website.

Comment: Can you give a modified example? I'm more of a visual learner so it would probably make more sense to me if I saw it written out.